# Is this Sequence Bounded Above?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

I know the Sequence is increasing as $\Big(a_{n+1}-a_n> 0\Big)$ and it is bounded below as $a_1 = \frac{1}{2}$

But how do we know whether the sequence is bounded above or not .

Comment: Compare with $\int_{n+1}^{2n} \frac 1  xdx$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}<\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}<1.
$$